# move Rprofile from one computer to another

Tags: r, rprofile

I am trying to put a copy of my Rprofile from my work computer onto my home computer, but R does not seem to be able to find it.

I have tried several responses to similar questions including:

In Windows, you set the R_USER profile by opening up a command line and running:

```
SETX R_PROFILE_USER "C:/.../.Rprofile"

Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER")
[1] "C:/Users/Sally/Rprofile"
```

but this does not work.

I also tried:

```
 candidates <- c( Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE"),
                 file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "etc", "Rprofile.site"),
                 Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER"),
                 file.path(getwd(), ".Rprofile") )

Filter(file.exists, candidates)
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/etc/Rprofile.site"
```

I changed the location of the Rprofile file to match the Filter results with no luck.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

If anyone has any suggestions it would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Sally

Answer (score 0):

That is Windows for you -- you need to define `$HOME` as an evironment variable, or place it in `$USER` or ... whatever else they decide next.

On operating systems with an x or X in the name, `$HOME` is well defined and `~/.Rprofile` is found.

Possible workaround: just edit `$RHOME/etc/Rprofile.site` but remember that this file *will* vanish next time you upgrade R on Windows.